# Java Combo Box Error

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, parseint

I have added a combo box . It needs to have value 1 through 20 and needs to call method from the constructor. 
Now I am bad at placing codes. I get confused where I need to insert code and always end up getting errors.

I am getting error when i run my program. It says for combo box:No suitable method
I have named the box yearscombobox

Please help me fix the error. I do not know if i need to put array for having values 1 through 20? If so, I do not know where to place that code.
I have errors in line that I have written in BOLD in the code. Ok i tried bolding it. this code is little different when i copy it from net beans. Anything that has yearscomboox has error saying no suitable method. Help me. I am at your mercy. I hate Java

```
  package murach.ui;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import murach.business.FinancialCalculations;

  public class FutureValueFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   /** Creates new form FutureValueFrame */
    public FutureValueFrame() {
     initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
    * initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
    * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
   private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    monthlyPaymentTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    yearlyRateTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    calculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    **YearsComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();**
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    FutureValueList = new javax.swing.JList();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Future Value Calculator");
    setResizable(false);

    jLabel1.setText("Monthly Payment:");

    jLabel2.setText("Yearly Interest Rate:");

    jLabel3.setText("Number of Years:");

    jLabel4.setText("Future Value:");

    calculateButton.setMnemonic('c');
    calculateButton.setText("Calculate");
    calculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            calculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    exitButton.setMnemonic('x');
    exitButton.setText("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    YearsComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" }));
    YearsComboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            YearsComboBoxActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    FutureValueList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = { "Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(FutureValueList);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4))
            .addGap(16, 16, 16)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(yearlyRateTextField)
                    .addComponent(monthlyPaymentTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 115, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(YearsComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(calculateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1))))
            .addGap(36, 36, 36))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(monthlyPaymentTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(yearlyRateTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(YearsComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(calculateButton)
                .addComponent(exitButton))
            .addContainerGap(100, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>


private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    if (isValidData())
    {
        double p = Double.parseDouble(monthlyPaymentTextField.getText());
        double r = Double.parseDouble(yearlyRateTextField.getText());
        int y = Integer.parseInt(YearsComboBox.getItemCount());

        double fv = FinancialCalculations.calculateFutureValue(p, r, y);

        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        FutureValueList.setText(currency.format(fv));
    }
}                                               

private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void YearsComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
 int y = YearsComboBox.getSelectedIndex();

}

private boolean isValidData()
{
    SwingValidator sv = new SwingValidator();
    return
        sv.isPresent(monthlyPaymentTextField, "Monthly Investment") &&
        sv.isDouble(monthlyPaymentTextField, "Monthly Investment") &&
        sv.isPresent(yearlyRateTextField, "Interest Rate") &&
        sv.isDouble(yearlyRateTextField, "Interest Rate") &&
        sv.isPresent(YearsComboBox, "Number of Years") &&
        sv.isInteger(YearsComboBox, "Number of Years");
}

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // new FutureValueFrame().setVisible(true);  // generated code
            FutureValueFrame frame = new FutureValueFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JList FutureValueList;
public javax.swing.JComboBox YearsComboBox;
private javax.swing.JButton calculateButton;
private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField monthlyPaymentTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField yearlyRateTextField;
// End of variables declaration

  }
```

Comment: I ran your code and the YearsComboBox does contain the values from 1 to 20. So what is the problem you have?

Answer (score 4):

1. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , nobody knows rest of  classes ...,
2. there no issue to put `Integer` or `Double` value to the `Model` for [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) or [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
3. use J[FormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with `Number Formatter`,
4. then you can to reduce any possible exceptions from parsing `String` from / to `Integer` or `Double`
5. you can to use [JSpinner with SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) rather than `JComboBox`